# Migration HSQLDB to MySQL using MySQL Workbench 6.2

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, hsqldb

I've to migrate HSQLDB to MYSQL but I don't know how to configure Workbench. I tried to follow this instruction http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-overview-steps.html but I've failed. How to properely configure migration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB is not a supported source RDBMS in MySQL Workbench but you can try with the generic ODBC source in the wizard. But expect problems on the way, because there can be unhandled data types or untested input/output combinations for table fields and similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a database migration tool written in Java. These tools connect to databases via JDBC and are compatible with both HSQLDB and MySQL. One example is Flyway (flywaydb.org).

Comment: If written in java as said, Flyway cannot do migration from HSQLDB towards MySQL. The team calls migrations what should preferably be called versions. It is a versioning database tool.